# Programa não lê dados do arquivo corretamente

Tags: c

Eu tenho essas três structs:

```
   typedef struct {
     char codigopaciente[10];
     char nome[50];
     char telefone[50];
     int idade;
     char sexo;
  } paciente;

  typedef struct {
     char codigomedico[10];
     char nome[50];
     char especialidade[50];
     float valorconsulta;
 } medico;

 typedef struct {
     char codigopaciente[10];
     char codigomedico[10];
     char dataconsulta[10];
     char diadasemana[10];
 } consulta;
```

Daí, eu utilizo esse código no main:

```
arquivo1 = fopen("medico.dat", "r");
// Se o arquivo for vazio, a memória é alocada.
if (arquivo1 == NULL) {
    printf("Quantos medicos voce deseja cadastrar?\n");
    scanf("%d", &quantidade_medicos);
    m = malloc(quantidade_medicos * sizeof(medico));
    medicos_cadastrados = 0;
// Se o arquivo não for vazio, a memória é alocada junto com os registros presentes no arquivo.
} else {
    fread(&quantidade_arquivo, sizeof(int), 1, arquivo1);
    printf("Existem %d medicos nesse arquivo. Quantos mais voce precisa cadastrar?\n", quantidade_arquivo);
    scanf("%d", &quantidade_medicos);
    quantidade_medicos = quantidade_medicos + quantidade_arquivo;
    m = malloc(quantidade_medicos * sizeof(medico));
    quantidade_medicos = quantidade_arquivo;
    fread(m, sizeof(medico), quantidade_arquivo, arquivo1);
    fclose(arquivo1);
    }
```

(o código é parecido para os dois arquivos das outras structs)

E depois, quando o programa está para ser fechado e todas as operações de escrita foram feitas, utilizo esse código:

```
   arquivo1 = fopen("medico.dat", "w");
   fwrite(&medicos_cadastrados, sizeof(int), 1, arquivo1);
   fwrite(m, sizeof(medico), (medicos_cadastrados), arquivo1);
   free(m);
   fclose(arquivo1);
   arquivo2 = fopen("paciente.dat", "w");
   fwrite(&pacientes_cadastrados, sizeof(int), 1, arquivo2);
   fwrite(p, sizeof(paciente), (pacientes_cadastrados), arquivo2);
   free(p);
   fclose(arquivo2);
   arquivo3 = fopen("consulta.dat", "w");
   fwrite(&consultas_cadastradas, sizeof(int), 1, arquivo3);
   fwrite(c, sizeof(consulta), (consultas_cadastradas), arquivo3);
   free(c);
   fclose(arquivo3);
```

Já utilizei a mesma técnica em um outro exercício e os arquivos gerados não eram "legíveis" em um editor de texto, porém, o programa conseguia recuperar os dados corretamente. Porém, nesse código em especifico, os dados são recuperados parcialmente.

O que pode estar acontecendo nesse caso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que o seu problema está aqui:

```c
arquivo1 = fopen("medico.dat", "r");

...

arquivo3 = fopen("consulta.dat", "w");
```

Acho que você deveria usar `rb` e `wb` ao invés de `r` e `w`. Ou então algum outro modo como `ab`, `ab+`, `w+` ou `w+b`. O importante é manter o `b`de **binário**, pois os seus arquivos são em modo binário (lidos com `fread` e escritos com `fwrite`), e não modo texto.

De acordo com a tabela [deste site](http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/~azeredo/cursoC/aulas/c950.html), estes são os modos:

> - `r`: Abre um arquivo texto para leitura. O arquivo deve existir antes de ser aberto.
> - `w`: Abre um arquivo texto para gravação. Se o arquivo não existir, ele será criado. Se já existir, o conteúdo anterior será destruído.
> - `a`: Abre um arquivo texto para gravação. Os dados serão adicionados no fim do arquivo (*"append"*), se ele já existir, ou um novo arquivo será criado, no caso de o arquivo não existente anteriormente.
> - `rb`: Abre um arquivo binário para leitura. Igual ao modo `r` anterior, só que o arquivo é binário.
> - `wb`: Cria um arquivo binário para escrita, como no modo `w` anterior, só que o arquivo é binário.
> - `ab`: Acrescenta dados binários no fim do arquivo, como no modo `a` anterior, só que o arquivo é binário.
> - `r+`: Abre um arquivo texto para leitura e gravação. O arquivo deve existir e poder ser modificado.
> - `w+`: Cria um arquivo texto para leitura e gravação. Se o arquivo existir, o conteúdo anterior será destruído. Se não existir, será criado.
> - `a+`: Abre um arquivo texto para gravação e leitura. Os dados serão adicionados no fim do arquivo se ele já existir, ou um novo arquivo será criado, no caso de o arquivo não existir anteriormente.
> - `r+b`: Abre um arquivo binário para leitura e escrita. O mesmo que `r+` acima, só que o arquivo é binário.
> - `w+b`: Cria um arquivo binário para leitura e escrita. O mesmo que `w+` acima, só que o arquivo é binário.
> - `a+b`: Acrescenta dados ou cria uma arquivo binário para leitura e escrita. O mesmo que `a+` acima, só que o arquivo é binário.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Mas fiquei curioso porque tinha casos em que funcionava com `r` e com `w` normalmente e em outros dava problema.

Comment: @athosbr99 Provavelmente porque na maioria dos casos o resultado fica igual em qualquer modo, seja texto ou binário. Mas em alguns, o resultado é diferente. Em especial, caracteres de quebra-de-linha (`\r` e `\n`) tem tratamento diferente entre modo texto e modo binário. Quando representados como números, eles são o 13 e o 10, respectivamente.