# Problema com fscanf usando code::blocks e OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

Alguém sabe se há alguma restrição em usar `fscanf` em projetos que usam GLUT (OpenGL)? Eu estou tentando fazer algo simples... ler uma nuvem de pontos (x, y, z) de um arquivo texto, mas o `fscanf` não obtém os valores corretamente... O mesmo código em uma aplicação console no code::blocks funciona corretamente.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão do que possso ter feito de errado?

Código:

```
#include <windows.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int v1x;
    int vetor[9]; // 3 points

    FILE *occluded_triangles;

    occluded_triangles = fopen("occluded_triangles.txt", "rt");

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        fscanf(occluded_triangles, "%d", &v1x);
        vetor[i] = v1x;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", vetor[i]);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Estava com um problema parecido, e o problema era no codebloks. Estava passando um game que desenvolvi na conio2 para openGL, estava utilizando o projeto configurado para funcionar com GLUT no codebloks, até eu precisar abrir um arquivo estava tudo ok. A solução que encontrei foi incluir os links necessario para utilizar GLUT e assim trabalhar sem projeto no codebloks, funcionou. Muito desconfiei que era alguma m*** que eu estivesse fazendo, porém o mesmo código rodava fora do projeto e não rodava dentro do mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Embora o seu código contenha alguns `#include`s de bibliotecas do OpenGL, ele não está fazendo nada que utilize o OpenGL. As únicas funções de biblioteca que ele está utilizando são `fopen`, `fscanf`, `printf` e `system`.

Há um probleba na sua chamada a `fopen`. Você usa o modo `"rt"`. Este modo não existe. Provavelmente você deveria usar apenas `"r"`. De acordo com a tabela [deste site](http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/~azeredo/cursoC/aulas/c950.html) (que eu estou copiando [desta outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42564/132)), estes são os modos válidos:

> - `r`: Abre um arquivo texto para leitura. O arquivo deve existir antes de ser aberto.
> - `w`: Abre um arquivo texto para gravação. Se o arquivo não existir, ele será criado. Se já existir, o conteúdo anterior será destruído.
> - `a`: Abre um arquivo texto para gravação. Os dados serão adicionados no fim do arquivo (*"append"*), se ele já existir, ou um novo arquivo será criado, no caso de o arquivo não existente anteriormente.
> - `rb`: Abre um arquivo binário para leitura. Igual ao modo `r` anterior, só que o arquivo é binário.
> - `wb`: Cria um arquivo binário para escrita, como no modo `w` anterior, só que o arquivo é binário.
> - `ab`: Acrescenta dados binários no fim do arquivo, como no modo `a` anterior, só que o arquivo é binário.
> - `r+`: Abre um arquivo texto para leitura e gravação. O arquivo deve existir e poder ser modificado.
> - `w+`: Cria um arquivo texto para leitura e gravação. Se o arquivo existir, o conteúdo anterior será destruído. Se não existir, será criado.
> - `a+`: Abre um arquivo texto para gravação e leitura. Os dados serão adicionados no fim do arquivo se ele já existir, ou um novo arquivo será criado, no caso de o arquivo não existir anteriormente.
> - `r+b`: Abre um arquivo binário para leitura e escrita. O mesmo que `r+` acima, só que o arquivo é binário.
> - `w+b`: Cria um arquivo binário para leitura e escrita. O mesmo que `w+` acima, só que o arquivo é binário.
> - `a+b`: Acrescenta dados ou cria uma arquivo binário para leitura e escrita. O mesmo que `a+` acima, só que o arquivo é binário.

Além disso, é possível que o seu arquivo `occluded_triangles.txt` possa conter algo errado que faça o `fscanf` falhar.

Comment: O problema no código está no fopen! Se eu colocar "occluded_triangles = fopen("\\occluded_triangles.txt", "rt");", ou seja, acrescentando as duas barras invertidas no 'caminho' do arquivo, o código funciona. Talvez seja algo relacionado a GLUT, pois nunca precisei do "\\". Realmente ele não está fazendo nada com a OpenGL. Eu retirei todas as funções pois notei que o problema estava na leitura do arquivo ".txt". Obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: rt não deve ser utilizado. Não é padrão.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que explicar melhor o que é esta nuvem de pontos (x, y, z), e como quer exibir tal informação. Vou assumir que você pretende ler 9 números no arquivo e mostrá-los.

**Primeira opção:**
Tomando, por exemplo, que seu arquivo txt (aqui nomeado "meu_arquivo.txt") seja:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Basta simplificar seu código:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void)
{
    int i; 
    int vetor[9];

    FILE *arquivo;

    arquivo = fopen("meu_arquivo.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)     
        fscanf(arquivo, "%d", &vetor[i]);


    for (i = 0; i < 9; i ++)        
        printf("%d\n", vetor[i]);  


    fclose(arquivo);

    return 0;
}
```

Esse código gerará a saída :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Retire esse negócio de `system("pause")`, se o terminal estiver fechando utilize `getchar()` por questões de portabilidade. Sempre feche o arquivo com `fclose` e olhe direitinho as opções do `fopen`. Além disso, não encha seu programa de variáveis sem motivos (`v1x`) ou `#include`s desnecessários. Para finalizar, também seria prudente colocar um teste condicional caso o ponteiro para o arquivo retorne ou não NULL, e somente então executar as ações pretendidas com base nesse teste.

**Segunda opção:**
Para melhor resultado e ter menos linhas de código, aconselho utilizar o arquivo txt como

```
1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6,
7, 8, 9
```

e fazer o código:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    int vetor[9] = {

        #include "meu_arquivo.txt"
    };

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        printf("%d\n", vetor[i]); 

    return 0;
}
```

Isso evita o uso de `fscanf`, `fopen` e `fclose`. Seria ideal para seu caso.

Answer (score 1):

Como você mesmo descobriu, nos comentários à uma das respostas, o problema é a "\" dentro da stringng - isso não tem nada a ver com OpenGL, e pouco tem a ver com  o "fopen" - o problema é que o Windows usa o mesmo caractére para separar diretórios que usado como caractére de escape em strings em C.

Você deve usar sempre duas barras invertidas "\" dentro de strings em C e em outras linguagens, para representar uma única "\". A "\" simples é usada como prefixo de caractéres especiais, por exemplo: "\t" para um caractere "tab", "\n" para uma nova linha, etc...

O problema não está visível na sua listagem, só no seu comentário  - é melhor você atualizar a listagem e colocar a "\" lá.