# Como calcular blobs em C?

Tags: c, blob, pixels

Como posso calcular uma zona de pixels em C?

Os pixeis, R G B são dados a partir de um ficheiro.
O utilizador tem de inserir um R, G e B e um desvio, tal como está na função calcular zonas.

A partir disso, é suposto que verifique se cada pixel do ficheiro é semelhante a esse RGB, e se for, cria zona e verifica a vizinhança desse pixel. Se forem semelhantes, adiciona a essa zona.

Comecei fazer assim, mas depois disso não sei por onde seguir.
Neste caso, pretendo calcular blobs, ou seja, ver se os pixeis da vizinhança de um certo pixel são semelhantes, e assim criar uma zona.

```
int LerFicheiro(char *fi, IMAGEM *Imag){

    int i, j ,nC, nL,ncanais;
    char nome;
    FILE *f;
    PIXEL *p;
    PIXEL **m;
    p = (PIXEL *)malloc(sizeof(PIXEL));
    f = fopen(fi, "r");  // abre um ficheiro qualquer
    while (!feof(f))
    {
        fread(&nome, sizeof(IMAGEM), 1, f);  // nome da imagem
        fread(&Imag->NLINHAS, sizeof(IMAGEM), 1, f); //  nº linhas
        fread(&Imag->NCOLUNAS, sizeof(IMAGEM), 1, f);  // nº colunas
        fread(&Imag->NCANAIS, sizeof(IMAGEM), 1, f);  // nº canais
        m=criarmatriz(Imag->NLINHAS, Imag->NCOLUNAS);
        for (i = 0; i <= Imag->NLINHAS; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < Imag->NCOLUNAS; j++)
            {
                fread(&m[i][j].R, sizeof(IMAGEM), 1, f);
                fread(&m[i][j].G, sizeof(IMAGEM), 1, f);
                fread(&m[i][j].B, sizeof(IMAGEM), 1, f);


            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return INSUCESSO;
}  
int calcularZonas(IMAGEM *Imag, int R, int G, int B, int D) {

    int i, j;
    PIXEL *p;
    BLOCO *b;
    PIXEL **m;
    b = (BLOCO *)malloc(sizeof(BLOCO));
    for (i = 0; i <= Imag->NLINHAS; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < Imag->NCOLUNAS; j++)
        {
            if ((m[i][j].R>= R - D) &&( m[i][j].R <= R + D))        // vai comparar o R dado pela função com o pixel da imagem, guardado na matriz.
            {
                if ((m[i][j].G >= G - D) && (m[i][j].G <= G + D))
                {
                    if ((m[i][j].B >= B - D )&& (m[i][j].B <= B + D))
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return INSUCESSO;
}

    typedef struct {

        int R, G, B;
    } *ptPIXEL, PIXEL;

    typedef struct Elem {

        PIXEL *info;

        struct Elem *seg;

        struct Elem *ant;
    } *ptELEMENTO, Elemento;

    typedef struct {

        int NLINHAS, NCOLUNAS, NCANAIS;

        Elemento *inicio;

        int nEl;

    } *ptIMAGEM, IMAGEM;

    IMAGEM *criar_lista() {

        IMAGEM *L;

        L = (IMAGEM *) malloc(sizeof(IMAGEM));

        L->inicio = NULL;

        L->nEl = 0;

        return L;
  }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde está o código que define o que é `BLOCO` e o que há dentro de `criarmatriz`? O que é o número de canais da imagem? Esse formato de arquivo foi definido por você ou não?

Comment: Tenho uma resposta escrita pela metade, mas não entendi alguns detalhes do que você pretende fazer exatamente para criar essas zonas. Pixels de mesma cor em regiões diferentes pertencem às mesmas zonas? Se você tem uma zona de cor (0, 128, 0) e outra (0, 192, 0), e ambas tem como distância 50, onde você colocaria um pixel de cor (0, 160, 0)?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Bloco é a estrutura que vai receber as listas de blobs. A função criamatriz, vai criar uma matriz que guarda os pixeis da imagem. por exemplo, m[0][0] guarda o 1º pixel.  o nº de canais, neste caso 3 significa que cada pixel tem 3 canais, o R, o G e o B.
O ficheiro com os pixeis já nos é dado.

Comment: @VictorStafusa  a função de calcular zonas tem como parâmetros de entrada um R, G e B e um Desvio. Estes RGB são inseridos pelo utilizador, e é suposto que todos os pixeis sejam comparados a esse RGB com o desvio, para saber se são semelhantes ou não. Caso um pixel seja semelhante, vai verificar os pixeis vizinhos. Se estes forem semelhantes, cria-se uma zona(blob), e ambos fazem parte da mesma zona. Neste caso a vizinhança é o pixel da linha de cima, de baixo, à esquerda e à direita do pixel que é semelhante ao RGB dado na função

Comment: Mas disso eu já sabia. A minha pergunta é se duas áreas de mesma cor, porém distantes, são partes de uma mesma zona ou não.

Comment: O nome do arquivo realmente está dentro do ficheiro? Se sim, como você sabe onde acaba o nome e começa o número de linhas? O número de linhas, número de colunas e número de canais são representados com quantos bits? São *little-endian* ou *big-endian*?

Comment: @VictorStafusa não, duas áreas da mesma cor, porém distantes são zonas diferentes.
Dentro do ficheiro, a primeira linha contém o nome da imagem, a segunda o tamanho da imagem.

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta e postar nela o conteúdo do ficheiro? Se for muito grande, põe num link externo. Daí ajusto a resposta para ficar de acordo.

Comment: O ficheiro tem cerca de 3 imagens, que dá um total de 18 milhões de linhas, mas é basicamente tudo o mesmo. vou colocar então uma parte do ficheiro. cada pixel contém os valores de 3 linhas. Cada linha destinha se ao R ou ao G ou ao B.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Teste ela e diga se funciona. E se não funcionar, diga onde deu errado se possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro que esses seus `struct`s estão confusos. Por exemplo, a sua estrutura `Elem` não parece representar nada que tenha algum valor real. O ideal seria que a imagem contivesse diretamente os pixels e nada mais. A função que cria uma imagem se chama `criar_lista()`, o que é confuso.

A leitura dos valores da imagem também estão errados, pois se você está lendo um `int`, deveria usar `sizeof(int)` e não `sizeof(IMAGEM)`. Aliás, [`fread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) é para ler dados em formato binário (veja mais sobre isso [nessa outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42564/132)). Mas no seu caso, o formato é textual. Por isso, use [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) ou [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

Outra coisa é que é preciso manter a consistência das regras de nomenclatura da linguagem. Logo, nomes de variáveis e campos devem ser minúsculos.

O primeiro passo são os `#include`s:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

As estruturas que precisamos são o `PIXEL` e a `IMAGEM` que os contém:

```
typedef struct PIXEL {
    char r, g, b; // O tipo char sempre ocupa 1 byte na memória.
} PIXEL;

typedef struct IMAGEM {
    int linhas, colunas;
    PIXEL *pixels;
} IMAGEM;
```

Em seguida, uma função para criar uma `IMAGEM`, destruí-la e acessar seus pixels:

```
IMAGEM *criar_imagem(int linhas, int colunas) {
    IMAGEM *im = (IMAGEM *) malloc(sizeof(IMAGEM));
    im->inicio = pixels;
    im->linhas = linhas;
    im->colunas = colunas;
    im->pixels = (PIXEL *) malloc(linhas * colunas * sizeof(PIXEL));
    return im;
}

PIXEL *acessar_pixel(IMAGEM *im, int linha, int coluna) {
    return &(im->pixels[linha * im->colunas + coluna]);
}

void destruir_imagem(IMAGEM *im) {
    free(im->pixels);
    free(im);
}
```

Para ler o conteúdo dos diferentes tipos de linhas de um ficheiro, podemos fazer essas funções:

```
int ler_string(FILE *f, char *dst, int s) {
    return fgets(dst, s, f) != NULL;
}

int ler_tres_ints(FILE *f, int *a, int *b, int *c) {
    char buffer[200];
    if (!ler_string(f, buffer, 200)) return 0;

    char *end_a, *end_b, *end_c;
    errno = 0;

    int x = strtol(buffer, &end_a, 10);
    if (end_a == &buffer || errno || *end_a != ' ') return 0;

    int y = strtol(&(end_a[1]), &end_b, 10);
    if (end_b == end_a || errno || *end_b != ' ') return 0;

    int z = strtol(&(end_b[1]), &end_c, 10);
    if (end_c == end_b || errno || *end_c != 0) return 0;

    *a = x;
    *b = y;
    *c = z;
    return 1;
}

int ler_int(FILE *f, int *a) {
    char buffer[200];
    if (!ler_string(f, buffer, 200)) return 0;

    char *end;
    errno = 0;

    int x = strtol(buffer, &end, 10);
    if (end == &buffer || errno || *end != 0) return 0;

    *a = x;
    return 1;
}
```

Finalmente, para ler o conteúdo da imagem de um ficheiro, podemos fazer isso:

```
IMAGEM *ler_imagem_do_ficheiro(const char *nome) {
    // 1. Abre o ficheiro. Retorna NULL se não conseguir abri-lo.
    FILE *f = fopen(nome, "rb");
    if (f == NULL) return NULL; // Erro ao abrir o ficheiro.

    // 2. Obtém o tamanho do ficheiro aberto.
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int sz = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    // 3. Lê o nome da imagem, e o descarta, pois não precisamos dela.
    char nome[200];
    ler_string(f, nome, 200);

    // 4. Lê o número de linhas, colunas e canais do ficheiro.
    int linhas = 0, colunas = 0, canais = 0;
    int a = ler_tres_ints(f, &linhas, &colunas, &canais); // Lê os números.

    // 5. Se não conseguiu ler o número de linhas, colunas e/ou canais, então o
    // ficheiro está incompleto. Fecha-o e retorna NULL. O mesmo ocorre se o número
    // de canais for diferente de 3.
    if (!a || canais != 3) {
        fclose(f);
        return NULL; // Erro: Ficheiro incompleto ou número de canais diferente de 3.
    }

    // 6. Cria a imagem na memória.
    IMAGEM *im = criar_imagem(linhas, colunas);

    // 7. Lê todos os pixels da imagem.
    for (int linha = 0; linha < linhas; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < colunas; coluna++) {

            // 7.1. Lê o conteúdo do pixel.
            PIXEL *p = acessar_pixel(im, linha, coluna);
            int x = ler_int(f, &(p->r));
            int y = ler_int(f, &(p->g));
            int z = ler_int(f, &(p->b));

            // 7.2. Se não conseguiu ler o pixel, então o ficheiro está
            // incompleto. Fecha-o, destrói a imagem incompleta e retorna NULL.
            if (!x || !y || !z) {
                fclose(f);
                destruir_imagem(im);
                return NULL; // Erro: Ficheiro incompleto.
            }
        }
    }

    // 8. Verifica se chegou no final do ficheiro e o fecha. Se não tiver, então
    // há dados excedentes após o último pixel. Considera isso como uma
    // imagem defeituosa/corrompida, e portanto a destrói, fecha o ficheiro.
    a = ftell(f);
    fclose(f);
    if (a != sz) {
        destruir_imagem(im);
        return NULL; // Erro: Há dados excedentes após o que seria o fim da imagem.
    }

    // 9. Se conseguiu abrir o ficheiro, ler todos os pixels e fechar sem que nenhum
    // erro tivesse ocorrido, então a imagem está pronta e deve ser retornada.
    return im;
}
```

É importante frisar que o formato desse ficheiro é importante:

- Uma linha contendo o nome da imagem. Entretanto, o nome da imagem é desconsiderado.
- Uma linha com três números decimais separados por um único espaço sem espaços antes do primeiro número ou depois do último. Esses números são o número de linhas, o número de colunas e o número de canais da imagem. O número de canais deve ser 3.
- Vários números representando componentes de pixels, cada um em uma linha. Eles são apresentados na ordem R, G e B, de forma que cada pixel é representado por três linhas numéricas.
- Não deve haver nada além dos dados do último pixel.
  Três `int`s representando a largura, a altura e o número de canais seguido dos pixels na ordem R, G e B, sendo um byte para cada componente. É importante que o ficheiro contenha todos os pixels e que não exista nada mais além do último pixel. Além disso, para que a função não rejeite o ficheiro de entrada e retorne `NULL`, os três `int`s do começo do ficheiro devem ter o *endianess* correto, o tamanho de cada um deles tem que ser `sizeof(int)` e o número de canais deve ser 3. O nome da imagem não aparece dentro do ficheiro.

O próximo passo é achar as zonas. Para isso, vamos criar uma estrutura semelhantes à imagem. No entanto, ao invés de armazenar as cores de cada pixel, armazena o número da zona:

```
typedef struct ZONEAMENTO {
    int linhas, colunas, zonas;
    int *pixels;
} ZONEAMENTO;
```

Feito isso, precisaremos de funções para criar, destruir e acessar os números de zona dessa estrutura:

```
ZONEAMENTO *criar_zoneamento(int linhas, int colunas) {
    ZONEAMENTO *z = (IMAGEM *) malloc(sizeof(ZONEAMENTO));
    z->inicio = pixels;
    z->linhas = linhas;
    z->colunas = colunas;
    z->zonas = 0;
    z->pixels = (int *) calloc(linhas * colunas, sizeof(int));
    return z;
}

int acessar_numero_de_zona(ZONEAMENTO *z, int linha, int coluna) {
    return z->pixels[linha * z->colunas + coluna];
}

int definir_numero_de_zona(ZONEAMENTO *z, int linha, int coluna, int zona) {
    z->pixels[linha * z->colunas + coluna] = zona;
}

void destruir_zoneamento(ZONEAMENTO *z) {
    free(z->pixels);
    free(z);
}
```

Feito isso, podemos começar a mapear as zonas:

```
ZONEAMENTO *calcular_zonas(IMAGEM *im, int r, int g, int b, int d) {
    ZONEAMENTO *z = criar_zoneamento(im->linhas, im->colunas);

    // Percorre cada pixel da imagem.
    for (int i = 0; i < im->linhas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < im->colunas; j++) {

             // Tenta marcar a zona do pixel e de todo o blob a ele pertencente.
             // Se conseguir, contabiliza mais uma zona.
             if (marcar_zona(im, z, i, j, r, g, b, d)) {
                 z->zonas++;
             }
        }
    }
    return z;
}
```

Agora, vamos ver essa função `marcar_zona`:

```
int marcar_zona(IMAGEM *im, ZONEAMENTO *z, int i, int j, int r, int g, int b, int d) {
    // Se o pixel está fora do limite da imagem, não marca nada.
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= im->linhas || j >= im->colunas) return 0;

    // Se este pixel já está marcado com algum número de zona, pule ele.
    if (acessar_numero_de_zona(z, i, j) != 0) return 0;

    // Obtém o pixel e suas cores.
    PIXEL *p = acessar_pixel(im, i, j);

    // Se este pixel tem uma cor muito diferente da que é esperada, pule ele.
    if (abs(p->r - r) > d || abs(p->g - g) > d || abs(p->b - b) > d) return 0;

    // Se chegamos aqui, marca o pixel como pertencente
    // a uma nova zona que está se formando.
    definir_numero_de_zona(im, i, j, z->zonas + 1);

    // Marca recursivamente os pixels vizinhos.
    marcar_zona(im, z, i + 1, j, r, g, b, d);
    marcar_zona(im, z, i - 1, j, r, g, b, d);
    marcar_zona(im, z, i, j + 1, r, g, b, d);
    marcar_zona(im, z, i, j - 1, r, g, b, d);

    // Retorna que a zona foi marcada com sucesso.
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!